# Gimp-level JPEG compression with Imagemagick

Tags: gimp, compression, imagemagick, image-processing

I have a batch of images I want to compress. There are hundreds, so I'd like to use CLI tools.

The images have the following characteristics.

```
$ identify 100.jpg 
100.jpg JPEG 639x426 639x426+0+0 8-bit sRGB 319KB
```

If I resize them with GIMP and export with these settings

[image]

I get a 20kB file of very acceptable quality.

```
$ identify c.jpg 
c.jpg JPEG 400x267 400x267+0+0 8-bit sRGB 20KB
```

If I resize it with Imagemagick's convert, however, as follows

```
$ convert 100.jpg -quality 50% -resize 400x267  c_im.jpg
```

I get a much larger file, without significant improvements in quality.

```
$ identify c_im.jpg 
c_im.jpg JPEG 400x267 400x267+0+0 8-bit sRGB 86.6KB
```

Even if I reduce the quality or the size further, I cannot get a file as small as what GIMP produces, unless I go so far that the image degenerates beyond recognition.

And even if I tick the EXIF and thumbnail boxes in GIMP, the size only grows up to about 43kB.

Is there a way to obtain the compression levels of GIMP with CLI tools, or in some automated manner?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a very helpful post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261855/recommendation-for-compressing-jpg-files-with-imagemagick)

The options I am using are these:

```
convert 100.jpg -strip -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 50% -resize 400x267  c_im.jpg
```

The `strip` option is really the key. From 85kB down to 16kB, just like that. Apparently it only removes comments and profiles, which I don't need.

The blur results in a slight size reduction but the loss in crispness is noticeable, so use at your discretion.

```
$ identify c_im.jpg 
c_im.jpg JPEG 400x267 400x267+0+0 8-bit sRGB 15.7KB
```